# Zend file Transfer

Tags: file, zend-framework, transfer

I have problem with upload.
this is my code:

> $upload->addFilter('Rename',array('target'=>$path,'overwrite'=>true));

and error:

> Warning: rename(C:\xampp\htdocs\laptop/public/_upload/laptop/50\1.JPG,C:\xampp\htdocs\laptop/public/_upload/laptop/50/1.JPG) [function.rename]: The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Filter\File\Rename.php on line 186

Comment: Could you please show more code, so the context becomes clearer?

Comment: Can you provide the sample value for `$path` and add the initialization of $upload.

Comment: did you got any solution? I'm also having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$upload->addFilter('Rename',array('target'=>$path,'overwrite'=>true));
```

Needs:

```
$upload->addFilter('Rename',array('target'=>$path,'overwrite'=>true), **string Files**);
```